# Behavior of @VisibleForTesting annotation on scala

Tags: scala, junit, mockito, guava, specs2

I'm testing a method I added to a scala class whose constructor is marked as private. It is accessed via a singleton Object, which does tons of other things that I don't want to touch.

```
class DummyClass private (config: DummyConfig) extends Runnable {

   def refresh() = {
       // Does tons of things
   }

   def updateProperty() = {
      // My method
   }
}

Object DummyClass {
  def apply(config: DummyConfig) = {
     val clss = new DummyClass(config)
     clss.refresh()
     new Thread(clss).start()
     clss
  }
}
```

In my JUnit (Specs/Mockito), I just want to create an object of that class and test the single method that I added, without it calling refresh or starting a thread.

Even when I add guava's annotation @VisibleForTesting over class DummyClass, I'm not able to use the constructor in the JUnit test. 
Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where is this `@VisibleForTesting` annotation coming from? Is it the one provided by the Guava library?

Most likely, this is just an **informative** annotation, just used to document the fact that you gave a more relaxed visibility to a method/constructor simply to allow unit testing.

In your case you would have to *actually* change the visibility of the constructor:

```
package p

class DummyClass private[p] (config: DummyConfig) extends Runnable {

   def refresh() = {
       // Does tons of things
   }

   def updateProperty() = {
      // My method
   }
}
```

Here if you put your unit test in the package `p` you can access the constructor since it is now package private. Add the annotation to indicate that no production code is allowed to call the constructor (but again, it will depend on the good behavior of the other developers working on the project, the compiler will not enforce anything based on the annotation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's right. It's coming from Guava. Is there a way to provide access to a whitelisted set of classes instead? This seems a bit too broad.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `@VisibleForTesting` is typically used to document that a method or field that would otherwise be `private` is package-private, but only to make it easier to test.

Comment: I left the DummyClass to be private and added a `private[util] def testDummyService(config: DummyConfig)` to the singleton method. That way we're making it explicit that the function is to be used only to get a test instance.

Comment: That is a way to do it yes. You can't white list a set of function like you would do in C++. Package private is not a bad restriction, one would assume that you are in control of your package.